# How to send django models into a template with additional custom fields?

Tags: python, django

I faintly remember seeing this done before in tutorials in the past. However, im having trouble finding out exactly how in the docs currently.

Suppose we had a model called Post. This model has a field called timestamp. However, when we send this model into the template we don't care about timestamps. Instead, we want the more popular "age" (created X mins/hrs ago), which thankfully, can be deduced from the timestamp.

Instead of creating a whole new field for timestamp, and instead of using custom template tags, can we somehow add a field to a model temporarily before sending it over to our template?

Ex.

```
# views.py
# Is the below code right? do I need to save()?
posts = Posts.objects.filter(...).filter(...)[:X]
for post in posts:
     # Post does not have an age field, we are creating one
     # temporarily before sending it to the template
     post.age = some_function(post.timestamp) 

return render_to_response(template, {'posts' : posts}, etc...)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make it a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) on the model.

```
class Post(Model)
  @property
  def age(self):
    return now() - self.timestamp
```

Comment: What are the implications between @properties and django? Will this be treated like a regular field? I didn't want a column for age to be created. If no column is created, how exactly are these properties handled? And more importantly, in the actual template, is the "age" property actually accessible?

Comment: Properties never become a field in the table. They are handled by the model class itself. All attributes of any object passed to a template renderer are accessible.

Comment: Thanks. If you know, still curious, does my example code above work? When I tried it, it fails to work, but I think maybe there is a syntax error somewhere...

Comment: It probably won't, since either your iteration in the view consumes the iterator, or the models are generated from the table anew.

Comment: I'll go with your solution, it's very good. But besides this decorator, is there no other way to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: You could use a no-argument method. But this way's prettier.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by a no argument method? Thanks

Comment: A method that only has `self` in the signature.

Comment: Can you please give a brief example of a solution to the above problem using this no-argument solution. Sorry it's not really clicking with me how this can solve the problem, thanks.